# Using a tally array to keep counts of another array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program that reads through a .txt file of weather data, and among other things, keep count of various weather patterns for each day of the year.

The .txt file has 365 lines of various values (one line of values for each day of the year).  Each line houses the high temp, low temp, and Weather status (formatted as a `String` of six 1's and 0's, with a 1 indicating that Fog/Rain/Snow/Hail/Thunder/Tornado occurred on that day). For example, the `String 011000`, would indicate that both rain and snow occurred.

Sample weather file looks like (line breaks for spacing):

High, Low, Weather String:

45, 32.4, 100000

43.2, 35, 100001

50.2, 32.1 101101

I have completed the vast majority of the program that traces through the weather.txt file and keeps track of the yearly high and yearly low, yet am having trouble tallying the weather status for each type (6 types).  I realize I don't do the best in explaining, but my goal is to keep count, for all 365 formatted String values, how many 1's for each index of the String.  So in looking at the sample weather file above, my end result would be [3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2].

In the pasted method below, I pass in a `String array` (I created a `String array` previously in the program, which houses all 365 String formatted values... [100001, 100000, 101101, ...]). In this method, I created a new `tally array` with 6 values.  I am trying to write a loop that traces through the passed in `weather array` (365 values), and increases the `tally array index` if a 1 occurs at the said index.  The final `tally array` would look something like [101, 31, 3, 218, 42, 101]...made up numbers for sample output.

The logic is giving me a lot of trouble.  Assuming I have done my bit in explaining this, can anyone offer me advice.

Note - the class constant of NUMBER_OF_WEATHER_TYPES is set to 6.

```
public static int[] getWeatherCounts(String[] weather) {
    int[] tally = new int[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_WEATHER_TYPES; j++) {
            if (weather[j].charAt(j) == 1) {
                tally[j]++;
            }
            return tally;
        }
    }

    return tally;
}
```

Whole program for context:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WeatherInfo {    
public static final int DAYS_PER_YEAR = 365;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_WEATHER_TYPES = 6;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String firstArgs = args[0];
    Scanner input = null;

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Error"); //Look more into this!!!!
    } else {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File(firstArgs));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    String lineDiscard = input.nextLine();

    double[] highs = new double[DAYS_PER_YEAR];
    double[] lows = new double[DAYS_PER_YEAR];
    String[] weather = new String[DAYS_PER_YEAR];

    for (int i = 0; i < DAYS_PER_YEAR; i++) {
        input.next();
        input.next();
        highs[i] = input.nextDouble();
        lows[i] = input.nextDouble();
        weather[i] = input.next();
    }

    displayWeatherStatistics(highs, lows, weather);

}    

public static void displayWeatherStatistics(double[] highs, double[] lows, String[] weather) {
    double highTemp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double lowTemp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // for loop for highs
    for (int i = 0; i < highs.length; i++) {
        if (highs[i] > highTemp) {
            highTemp = highs[i];
        }
    }

    // for loop for lows
    for (int i = 0; i < lows.length; i++) {
        if (lows[i] < lowTemp) {
            lowTemp = lows[i];
        }
    }

    // printouts for the low and high temps of the year...need to fix this a bit
    System.out.println("Highest Temp: " + highTemp + " (F)");
    System.out.println("Lowest  Temp: " + lowTemp + " (F)");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getWeatherCounts(weather)));


}

public static int[] getWeatherCounts(String[] weather) {
    int[] tally = new int[6];


    for (int i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_WEATHER_TYPES; j++) {
            if (weather[i].charAt(j) == 1) {
                tally[j]++;
            }
             return tally;
        }



    }

     return tally;
}
```

}

Comment: Create a weather object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's hard to tell without seeing your whole program. But it looks to me like

```
if (weather[j].charAt(j) == 1) {
    tally[j]++;
}
return tally;
```

should be

```
if (weather[i].charAt(j) == '1') {
    tally[j]++;
}
// omit the return tally, we don't want to do that until the end
```

Comment: I edited the post to add in full program at bottom.  Your logic makes sense to me, but the printed output is still giving me the tally array at the auto-initialized version...[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: In getWeatherCounts, you are returning tally in 2 different places. Delete the first one.

Comment: Interesting enough, I tried that and still no go.  My tally array still reads from its created values [ 0 0 0 0 0 0].

Comment: Darn.  What a stupid error in the end.  I did not have '' around my 1.  Thanks for your help, however, it guided me well.